# Update Query That Includes a Join

Tags: sql, asp.net, t-sql, gridview

I've got a gridview which shows data using the below SELECT statement.

```
SELECT  Categories.Description AS Category,  Files.FileID,  
        Filename, Files.Description,  IsPublished, Files.IsArchived
FROM Files 
INNER JOIN Categories 
   ON Files.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
WHERE Files.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
```

I now need an UPDATE statement to edit all of these columns. I can't get my head around doing this with two tables. I've produced the following but it doesn't do anything when I tried to edit a column.

```
UPDATE [Files] 
SET [CategoryID] = @CategoryID, [Filename] = @Filename, [Description] = 
@Description, [IsPublished] = @IsPublished, [IsArchived] = @IsArchived  
WHERE [Files.ID] = @FileID
```

Comment: If you're using both inside an stored procedure you can do something like this: `SELECT Categories.Description AS Category INTO @CategoryID, [other values],... FROM Files INNER JOIN Categories ON Files.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID; ` then do the update with those values you saved before.

Comment: Please post the entire update syntax (the lines around it).

Comment: This is probably ASP.NET.  Please tag

Comment: This is my entire update code

Comment: Show where that code is in you program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need two statements. Your category record needs to exist before the files record because it's referenced in the other table.

If you have a foreign key constraint it'll throw an error.